# How do you set a line's width when drawing in Android?

Tags: android

How to set line width? What method is used for it?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Check out **[`Paint.setStrokeWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29)**.

You draw by making various **[`Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html)** objects. The objects themselves are separated from the instructions about how to draw them; that's covered by the **[`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)** class. `Paint` instances have a method that allows you set the width of the stroke that will be used to draw the objects, **[`setStrokeWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29)**, which is what you want.