# Android how to draw line?

Tags: android, android-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you set a line's width when drawing in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963686/how-do-you-set-a-lines-width-when-drawing-in-android)

I've seen [How to draw a line in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android) but how can I set line width? I tried to set Paint

```
    colorCenter = new Paint();
    colorCenter.setAntiAlias(true);
    colorCenter.setStrokeWidth(100);
    colorCenter.setColor(0xFF00FFFF);
```

then in `onDraw()`

```
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 40, 40, colorCenter);
```

but it always 1px.

I also tried to find class `LineShape` and use it with `ShapeDrawable`, but there is no such class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add..

```
  colorCenter.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Answer (score 0):

get the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and use [drawLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint)

Comment: I'm already doing that, but it's only 1px width, while I want more.

Comment: Did you try paint.setStrokeWidth(width)?